# Why is not a keyword for accessing "this" object outside anonymous function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, this, keyword, anonymous-function

When using anonymous functions, a common approach I have seen to pass
the object's `this` reference into the function in JavaScript, is this:

```
var that = this;

collection.forEach(function(e) {
  that.element = e;
});
```

Of course, this can be language agnostic and typing agnostic (JavaScript is just where I have met it the most).

So, and because I am curious of it, why hasn't `that` become a standard in the language, or in other languages? It does not seem to be an implementation problem, as it practically is an object reference and not anything more.

Of course, I am not focusing if it will be named "that" or "self" or "John", but its purpose: accessing the object via a reference inside the anonymous function.

Comment: If I use `self` instead of `that`, should Javascript add it as reserved keyword? This is just a work-around to access context in some cases, and not a language feature

Comment: The onomatology is not our problem, but its purpose: accessing the object instance inside anonymous function.

Comment: For that, JS has provided [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: The "problem" is already solved: `collection.forEach(e => this.element = e);`

Comment: @zerkms worth to mention **in ES6**

Comment: @zerkms forEach is just one function. What if you have defined your own anonymous function?

Comment: @NickL. what if you wanted to refer to the object 2 levels up? PS: my code is not about `forEach` at all.

Comment: Okay, that is a good point.

Comment: *Aside*: Somehow I feel that the example in your question has a problem. Doesn't `forEach` expects a callback anyway?

Comment: @Abhitalks—and a *thisArg* can be supplied… ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your variable names are up to you. In my humble view, for instance, `that` is a very silly name to use as an alias for `this` as it means, you know, **that**. I generally stick to `thiswhatsit` or similar. But that's *me*. Some people really like `that`, and it's certainly become idiomatic. Some people like `self`. Or `me`. Or `_this`.

But if we're talking about ways of handling this issue *correctly*, within the language, ES5 and ES2015 added them:

- ES5 added [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.bind), which lets you set a specific `this` for a function. (ES5's `forEach` and [most of] its other array improvements also had a `thisArg` argument you could use.)
- ES2015 (aka ES6) added *arrow functions*, which inherit `this` from the context in which they're created (specifically, from the [enclosing lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions-runtime-semantics-evaluation)).

ES5 examples:

```
// Using thisArg:
collection.forEach(function(e) {
  this.element = e;
}, this);

// Using `bind`:
collection.someOtherMethod(function(e) {
    this.whatsit = foo;
}.bind(this));
```

ES6 example:

```
collection.forEach(e => {
    this.whatsit = foo;
});
```

Comment: what can i say, nice concise explanation. :) :)